# [Ant]How to add .so file into a jar and use it within jar(set the java.library.path)?

Tags: java, ant, jar, sigar

all. I'm trying to make a **bundle jar** containing [`Sigar`](http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar) library, which uses a `.so` as native support. I've zipped the `Sigar` into my.jar, when I run it from cmd, I have to type like this:

```
java -jar -Djava.library.path=~/path/to/lib/contains/so  my.jar
```

Yes this works, BUT I want to build a **bundle jar**, that, to say, contains .so into jar and use it within the jar. So my question is: **how to set the java.library.path pointing to .so files within that jar**. Finally, I want to make it like

```
java -jar my.jar (*)// hope to run it in this way
```

My `build.xml` looks like:

```
 27     <target name="jar" depends="compile">
 28         <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
 29         <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
 30             <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
 31             <fileset dir="${lib.dir}"  includes="*.so"/>
 32             <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.dylib"/>
 33             <manifest>
 34                 <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
 35             </manifest>
 36         </jar>
 37     </target>
```

By now, I just got UnsatisfiedLink Exception when I use run it in `(*)` way.

And another relevant question is: how to add a file to a specific location in the jar. In above example, `<fileset dir="${lib.dir}"  includes="*.so"/>` will put *.so in the root of jar, what if I want to change this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can’t do that. Native libraries are loaded by the operating system and it doesn’t support loading libraries from a JAR file. All Java libraries with native code I know of will extract their bundled native library to a temporary file and load it from there.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for reply, but how does stuff like [SqliteJDBC](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc‎) work? It uses several `.so` in its own jar.

Comment: As already said, they extract these `.so` files at runtime to a temporary file and load it from there. I don’t know any other way.

Comment: @Holger Thanks; At least I know what I can't do now.