# how to add a ".so" library in a Netbins project in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, java.library.path

I am a beginner in Netbeans JAVA development. I am searching for this solution for a long time and I have found some answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227045/how-to-add-so-file-to-the-java-library-path-in-linux) and [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710836/anthow-to-add-so-file-into-a-jar-and-use-it-within-jarset-the-java-library-p) but I can't make it work. I have also tried to run this command:

```
java -Djava.library.path=<path/to/the/file.so>
```

it gives me the help menu and did nothing.

please give me a detailed guide how to add .so library files in a Netbeans project in ubuntu.

Comment: java.library.path is a path to a directory, not the full file.

Comment: @stdunbar what will be the full command **java -Djava.library.path=</home/user/libs>** or **java -Djava.library.path=/home/user/libs**

Comment: The second one - `java -Djava.library.path=/home/user/libs`

Comment: @stdunbar it still showing the help menu